# Detect keyboard layout in GTK 3?

Tags: keyboard, internationalization, gtk3, xorg, wayland

Is there a way to detect the current keyboard layout (i.e. "us", "de", "de_CH", "it"...) under GTK3 in a portable way?
I don't need mswindows compatilibity, only linux, but it should work with both Xorg and Wayland backends and under different desktop environments.

I have found the [GdkKeymap](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Keyboard-Handling.html) class and `gdk_keymap_get_for_display()` function, but I can't see a function to get an identifier for the nationality/model/map of the keyboard.

Thank you